# Script crashes after a while

Tags: python

I am new here. :) My problem is, I wrote a python script for a doorbell. The script runs on a Raspberry Pi. I placed the Raspberry with the magnet contacts to my door. When you send the message "Doorbell on" via Telegram the script works. I get a Telegram message, if someone opens the door.
But after some minutes, I do not get any messages any more? Could someone please take a look what I did wrong?
Thank you very much!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*
import time
import socket
import sys
import telepot
import os
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
MAGNET_GPIO = 17
GPIO.setup(MAGNET_GPIO, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


UDP_IP = "1.1.1.1.1" 
UDP_PORT = 50000
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)


#Voreinstellung Telegramm
bot = telepot.Bot('123456789xxxxxxxxxx')
chat_id = xxxxxxxx1111111xxxxx1111111

telemes=0
door_dummy=0


def action(msg):
        chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
        command = msg['text']
        global telemes
        if command == 'Test':
            bot.sendMessage (chat_id, str("Test is good" ))
        if command == 'Reboot':
            bot.sendMessage (chat_id, str("See you later!" ))
            time.sleep(1.0)
            os.system("sudo reboot -h now")
        if command == 'Shutdown':
            bot.sendMessage (chat_id, str("Byeee!" ))
            time.sleep(1)
            os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")
        if command == 'Doorbell on':
            bot.sendMessage (chat_id, str("Doorbell is switched on"))
            telemes=1
        if command == 'Doorbell off':
            bot.sendMessage (chat_id, str("Doorbell is switched off"))
            telemes=0



MessageLoop(bot, action).run_as_thread()

while True:
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(MAGNET_GPIO) == 1 and telemes==1 and door_dummy==0:
            bot.sendMessage (chat_id, str("Türalarm!" ))
            sock.sendto('Dooralam', (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
            door_dummy=1
        if GPIO.input(MAGNET_GPIO) == 0 and telemes==1 and door_dummy==1 :
            door_dummy=0
```

Comment: Why do you have two nested `while True` loops?

Comment: Oh! Right you are. No idea, I will fix it. Do you think that causes the crash?

Comment: No, I think that you are sending too many calls to the device. Try is putting a `time.sleep(0.1)` at the end of the loop is solving the issue.

Comment: why you added 2 times while loop?